# Get specific lines from text file to another text file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, pcregrep

I have a plain text file with many lines, I am trying to get only the lines that start with `|V|` and `runtime`

What I have tried:

```
sed -e '/^\(runtime\|\\|V\\|\)/p' test.txt > test.out.txt
sed -e '/^(runtime\|\\|V\\|)/' test.txt > test.out.txt
sed -e '/^runtime/p' -e '/^\\|V\\|/p' test.txt > test.out.txt
sed -i.bak '/^\\|V\\|\|runtime/!d' test.txt
sed -i.bak '/^(\\|V\\|\|runtime)/!d' test.txt
pcregrep -M '^(runtime|\|V\|)*' test.txt > test.out.txt
egrep '^(runtime|\|V\|)*' test.txt > test.out.txt
```

Nothing works. I will either get an empty file or the same file duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? First some test data:

```
$ cat foo
|V|
runtime
foo
```

then the `greṕ` command:

```
$ grep "^\(|V|\|runtime\)" foo
|V|
runtime
```

Comment: That worked, which seems odd, cause I thought I tried that and it did not before... Well, at least its solved.